# KeyGenerator. разница между "AES" в KeyStore и без

Tags: java, android, безопасность, криптография, keystore

Есть ключик 256 бит, который генерится `KeyGenerator` таким способом:

```
 KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
 keyGen.init(256);
 key = keyGen.generateKey();
```

Я хочу его положить в `KeyStore`, в результате я генерю его так:

```
KeyGenerator keyGen2 = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, KEYSTORE_TYPE);
    keyGen2.init(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(ALIAS_ANY, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
            .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
            .setKeySize(256)
            .build());
    this.key = keyGen2.generateKey();
```

В результате encrypt/decrypt уменьшает эффективность в разы. Без `BLOCK_MODE_GCM` метод крашится в процессе, так же как и без `ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE`.

Чем отличается ключ по умолчанию от моей записи для `KeyStore`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что когда вы пишете в строке трансформации просто "AES", например:

```
 KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
```

По умолчанию выбирается метод трансформации `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding` - что конечно же намного быстрее чем метод сцепления блоков `GCM`

Вообще обычно принято выбирать:

```
AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding
```

что является более-менее промышленным стандартом.

Comment: а как дефолтный выглядит в записи для KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder ?

Comment: `BLOCK_MODE_CBC` и `ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7`